# viewshed analysis QGIS

Tags: qgis, viewshed

I'm trying to make a viewshed complemented Quamtun viewshed analysis in GIS, someone managed to do it? in my case not allow me to finish the process skips a misconception among other things tells me memory error, I guess it has to do with the ram, I have 2gb, if not otherwise think of.
Someone managed a viewshed in QGIS.

regards

Comment: It would be helpful to **edit** your post to include more details. What exact steps have you taken? What data are you using - how large is it, what format, etc.? What is the exact wording of the error message you get? 2GB is a pretty small amount of RAM for a system, but some software can divide up tasks to work with available RAM so that may not be the issue.

Comment: I am using a dem who weighs 13 mb. I have a shapefile just three points. I installed the viewshed analysis, leave the default settings and select ouput horizon, and I accept returned: An error occurred while the python code is executed

Answer (score 2):

I'm little late here... 
Did you properly project you raster to a metric system? I'm asking this because the "memory error" most often appears when you have your raster in degrees, but the analysis radius is in meters. (Which means the algorithm tries to calculate, like 5000 degrees, while the Earth has 360).

Comment: Thanks for replying, I had to move into another program because I could not fix it. Your observation may be true'll try. thank you very much

Comment: @Zoran Thanks! It seems that you explained my problem. Is it OK to stay in degrees and just specify a small range or is it necessary to reproject to get correct results?